# How do I create an auto-incrementing index/a sequence for an OrientDB database within an scheme of class

Tags: orientdb

As of OrientDB 2.2 there are sequences. Using them via API is well explained. But can I somehow add sequences to a schema? I want the database to automatically increment the sequence for a class (upon creation) and not doing it "manually" via the API. Have I missed something?

Comment: Hi @Fritz, what's your goal ? Is it to create a sequence only for a specific class ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I have a several classes (called class B,C,D) all inheriting from the same superclass A. For all of them there is a schema set up in the database. I want to define a sequence (auto-increment counter) within the superclass A in order to ensure, that upon creation of an B, C or D record there is a unique identifier automatically assigned to it. I do not want to do this via Java code since it should be run automatically in the background done by the database. Dies this help?

Comment: @LucaS: sorry, I did not address you. Do you have any idea any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Fritz, sorry for the late reply but I got busy. The sequence can also be created and managed by using the OSQL syntax but you have to call it during the insertion. Would you expect a situation like this: `B, C, D` --extend -> `A`; ------- `B, C, D` inherit from A the sequence (for a property, for example, called `ID`); ------- after the insertion of a 4 new records (one per class `A, B, C, D`) you expect a result like this: `A --> ID: 1`, `B --> ID: 2`, `C --> ID: 3`, `D --> ID: 4`. Is this your goal ?

Comment: @LucaS Hi, thanks. That's what I thought. I hoped to get it done without explicitly using it during the insertion call.